# How to show list of array data with a dynamic name in a flatlist with react native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

how to a render list of array data that has a dynamic name in a flatlist with react native?

this is the list of data below i would like to display in the flatlist

```
const movies = [
  {
    '4W2JJ0CLbvfLJzBUHORVaz6sAGv2': [
      {
        name: 'crystal',
        showWatched: 'cars',
        number: 1,
      },
      {
        name: 'barbra',
        showWatched: 'sunshine',
        number: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

the dynamic name is `'4W2JJ0CLbvfLJzBUHORVaz6sAGv2'`
i tried this below but noting isn't showing

```
  render() {
    const data = '4W2JJ0CLbvfLJzBUHORVaz6sAGv2';
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={movies[0].data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{item.name}</Text>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{item.showWatched}</Text>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{item.number}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: movies[0][data]

Comment: FYR https://medium.com/dailyjs/dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-eedea5fa8572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try
`data={movies[0][data]}`

For dynamic key, you should use bracket `[key]`